# Create multiple VMs based on single image

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I would like to use *libvirt* to run multiple Domains (VMs) based on the same image at once. The image itself should not be modified. The image should be considered as a starting point or template.

An obvious possibility would be to create a (temporary) copy for every domain. Since the image might take multiple GB, I don't want to create a full copy of it every time. It would like to store differences only. As I understand the documentation, external snapshots are using such technics. But it seems that snapshots are bound to a domain and I cannot use them as template.

According to [documentation of *qemu*](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html), I could use qemu directly while passing option `-snapshot`. As far as I'm not committing changes manually, it should work.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -snapshot -hda <image>
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar in *libvirt*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All you need is to use qcow2 backing files. In the next steps I'll assume that you already have your base image as a qcow2.

Create a disk image backed by your base image:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 \
                -o backing_file=/path/to/base/image.qcow2 \
                /path/to/guest/image.qcow2
```

Then in your guest, use `/path/to/guest/image.qcow2` as disk. This file will only get the difference with the base image.

Check qemu-img's man page for more details. qemu-img also has commands to commit the overlay file changes into the base image, rebase on another base, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out. :)

Comment: It works this way. I would like to avoid calling `qemu-img` directly but to create such images with *libvirt*, I have to define *storage-pools*. I thing I will use `qemu-img` directly since using libvirt seems to be much overhead in this case.

Comment: This command needed a `-F qcow2` to work for me.